# I am trying to install an add-in to MS Excel 2013 but I keep getting this error when I add the .xaml file in the Add-Ins tab

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to install this add-in:
https://members.excelcampus.com/list-search-add-in

error when opening my worksheet(.xlsx file)
[image: error when opening my worksheet(.xlsx file)]

My references window
[image: My references window]

Updated ribbon after installing Add-in
[image: Updated ribbon after installing Add-in]

Even though I get these errors, I still get the add-in ribbon and its functionalities but when I click on it, I get this...

on clicking on 'List Search' in above picture
[image: on clicking on 'List Search' in above picture]

I am fairly new to Excel and know nothing about Visual Basic.

Comment: There is probably a reference missing in the add-in. The screenshot you show is the reference of your `VBAProject` (or probably an empty workbook). Check the references of the add-in instead. The references are set per file (or per VBA project).

Comment: No I checked the add-in references too, none of them are marked missing

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt find any answers so I uninstalled MS Office 2013 and installed the 2010 version. Works fine now.